# Nesting razor C# in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-webpages

I'm nesting razor C# in JavaScript and I'm calling this function inside a button but when I press the button nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
    @functions{
        public void Validation()
        {
            StudentTable sTable = new StudentTable();
            var username = Request["username"];
            var password = Request["password"];
            var error = "";
        if(sTable.Login(username, password) != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Success.html");
        } 
        else
        {
            error = "Username/password entered is incorrect";
        }
</script>
}
}
<p>@error</p>
<button class="btn btn-default btn-primary" id="signin" type="submit" value="Signin" onclick="@functions" formmethod="post">Sign in</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing and matching javascript (which runs on the client) and C# (which runs on the server).  You will have to make an ajax request do do this validation or do this on a post back.